# C# Questions regarding Invoke, Invokerequired & Multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke, invokerequired

I have 2 forms running on different threads. Form2 will generate a string, send it back to form1 and update the richtextbox in form1. I got the code from my friend but I don't understand a part of it.

Could you please explain to me why do we need the condition:

```
if (this.f1_rtb_01.InvokeRequired) { }
```

And what do 2 lines below do?

```
SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
```

---

Full Code Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace PassingData2Forms
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string str_1;

    private void call_form_2()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Form2 inst_form2 = new Form2();
            inst_form2.ShowDialog();

            string result = inst_form2.SelectedString;
            this.SetText(result);
        }
    }

    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (this.f1_rtb_01.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            if (text != "")
            {
                this.f1_rtb_01.AppendText(text + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            else
            {
                this.f1_rtb_01.AppendText("N/A" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }

    private void f1_but_01_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread extra_thread_01 = new Thread(() => call_form_2());
        extra_thread_01.Start();            
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you running two forms on two threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part:

```
SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
```

causes the current form to invoke an instance of the `SetTextCallback` delegate, passing the variable `text` as a parameter. The delegate instance points to the `SetText()` method, which will, due to calling `this.Invoke()`, be executed on the same thread as the form.

Invocation is used to move the execution of code from a background thread to a form's/control's thread, thus making the execution thread-safe.

This part is just for checking if you are required to invoke:

```
if (this.f1_rtb_01.InvokeRequired)
```

If you aren't required to invoke that means that the code already runs on the form's or control's thread, and will throw an exception if you try to invoke.

Answer (score 1):

Each form runs on a different thread. Lets call them thread1 and thread2. Since you want to update something on thread2 from thread1, you would need to have those two threads to communicate with each other. And that's `invoke`'s job

the condition is to check whether or not invoke is required. If you are updating the string in thread1 on thread1 itself then no invoke is required otherwise it is.